# Access the clicked element

Tags: javascript

I have an element like this:

```
<p id='foo' onclick='go()'>hi</p>

function go() {
}
```

how do I get access to the element that generated the click (the p element in this case)? Do I just do:

```
function go() {
    var clicked = this;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<p id='foo' onclick='go(this)'>hi</p>

function go(elem) {
}
```

Comment: Cool... We posted the same answer, at exactly the same time :)

Answer (score 2):

You could pass `this` as an argument:

```
<p id='foo' onclick='go(this);'>hi</p>

function go(clicked) {
}
```