# How to access the id of the button who called a Javascript function using $(this)?

Tags: javascript, identifier

I am new to Javascript. I have set a couple of buttons on a page, like this:

```
<div id='MID_1_4'>
    <div id="login">logout</div>
    <button type="button" id="logout" onclick="loadXMLDoc2()">Logout</button>
</div>
...
```

I want to extract the id of the button who called `loadXMLDoc2()`. This method is defined as following:

```
function loadXMLDoc2() {

    var retr = $(this).attr("id");
    document.getElementById("L1_LEFT").innerHTML
        = retr;

}
```

Yet, `L1_LEFT` is set to `undefined` when I click on buttons. I thought `$(this)` meant "the current HTML element". If it is not the button then what is it? And how can I extract the button's id?

Comment: If you call a function "normally", which you do with `loadXMLDoc2()`, then `this` refers to `window`. You might want to read [more about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this). `$(this)` means create a jQuery object from whatever `this` refers to. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access the clicked element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498401/access-the-clicked-element)

Comment: You might want to just bind the event like `$("#logout").click(loadXMLDoc2)`; then `this` refers to the element.

Comment: @Felix Yes, I am learning to use JQuery too. I am not obsessed about using $(this) if it is not the recommended way. Just learning.

Comment: @pimvdb Do I understand you well if I say: the binding you suggest should be set in document-ready, and it would replace the need to define onclick="loadXMLDoc2()" in the <button> tag?

Comment: @JVerstry: Yes, exactly. That's what is usually done when using jQuery to bind functions to events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to `window` (the global object) inside the function, `this` refers to the `element` in the `onclick` handler.

while it's bad approach to do javascript in html, try this:

```
<div id='MID_1_4'>
    <div id="login">logout</div>
    <button type="button" id="logout" onclick="loadXMLDoc2(this)">Logout</button>
</div>

function loadXMLDoc2(elm) {

    var retr = elm.id;
    document.getElementById("L1_LEFT").innerHTML
    = retr;

}
```

A better approach is to separate HTML and javascript:

```
<div id='MID_1_4'>
    <div id="login">logout</div>
    <button type="button" id="logout">Logout</button>
</div>
```

(Somewhere in js file )

```
function loadXMLDoc2(elm) {

    var retr = elm.id;
    document.getElementById("L1_LEFT").innerHTML = retr;

}

$( document ).ready( function(){
//This function is executed after all elements on the page are ready to be manipulated

    $( "#logout" ).bind( "click",
        function(){
        loadXMLDoc2( this );
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: It works, but you say it is a bad approach. What would be the proper approach? Am I learning to use JQuery, but I am not obsessed about using $(this). I am in the learning curve.

Comment: +1 I was pleasantly surprised when I saw you used `elm.id` and weren't promoting `$(elm).attr("id")` or `$(elm).prop("id")`.  Stack Overflow is riddled with enough answers like that.

Comment: Why do you need to use an object at all just to retrieve simple properties? KISS!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, the variable this refers to the target element of an event handler. I think you are over complicating it, however. Try

```
var retr = this.id;
```

to obtain your id. KISS!!

Comment: I think the issue is that `this` was not the element creating the event when defining the event handler with a string in your HTML.   Also `this.id` is better than `this.getAttribute('id')`.

Comment: Using pimvdb's $("#logout").click(loadXMLDoc2) in document-ready and your var retr = this.id; in my method, I don't need to add a parameter to it. And it works!

Comment: The DOM is complicated, but not that bad. Good luck!